# How do I show a UISearchBar on the right side of a UINavigationItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I am trying to display a UISearchBar in place of the button shown on the right side of the UINavigationItem. I am using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *navRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:navRight];

    [searchBar release];
    [navRight release];
}
```

However, the displayed search bar is only a few pixels wide. I need to make it wider.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is it at all possible?

Comment: you can change the width of UIBarButtonItem by defining a frame using CGFrame or if possible add using IB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the UISearchBar's frame at some point.

e.x.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
```

**EDIT:** Regarding the button-esque artifact under the `UISearchBar`

The button-y thing that you see under the `UISearchBar` is actually a background element of the `UISearchBar`, not the result of the search bar overlapping a `UIBarButtonItem`.  Since there doesn't seem to be a nice way to hide this (and I hope someone can come along and correct me), I can only point you in the direction of a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867193/how-do-i-make-uisearchbar-in-a-uinavigationbar-resize-only-the-left-margin-using) that comes with the usual perils of SDK version dependence, inelegance, and potential for more headaches.

**EDIT 2:** Another potential solution

You could also set your UISearchBar's frame's height to 44 (the height of the navbar) and then the background should blend nicely with the navbar.  Based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867193/how-do-i-make-uisearchbar-in-a-uinavigationbar-resize-only-the-left-margin-using) SO post I recently saw.

Comment: Thank you! Stack Overflow rocks. Is there any way to hide the button under it?