# How do I make UISearchBar in a UINavigationBar resize only the left margin using a block animation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uisearchbar

I am trying to duplicate the UISearchBar animation seen in mobile Safari.  Instead of only moving the left margin, the UISearchBar Expands off the screen and then "jumps" into the proper location.  The downsizing is similarly uneven.  How can I make this animation even like the UISearchBar in mobile safari?

```
searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,175,44)] autorelease];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItemRight = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar] autorelease];
tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItemRight;


- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3
animations:^ {
CGRect newBounds = searchBar.bounds;
newBounds.size.width = 350;
searchBar.bounds = newBounds;
}];
[searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use UISearchDisplayController for this, you need to implement animation for your custom view controller.